# ArrayList - remove element, shifting list down?

Tags: java, android

This is a pretty straight-forward question...  Just couldn't  really find a straight-forward answer on the web.

Consider I have a `List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList();` and it is populated with 20 values.

If `listOfStings.get(0) = zero`, `listOfStrings.get(1) = one`, etc...

and I do `listOfStrings.remove(0)`

would `listOfStrings.get(0)` become `null`, or would the elements shift down so 
`listOfStrings.get(0)` becomes `one`?

Comment: Why dont you just try it yourself?

Comment: This question demonstrates a pathetic lack of effort... Either give it a try or read the documentation.

Comment: Did you just put so many efforts in writing a question, but none in researching this on the first level (e.g. Java API doc)?

Answer (score 12):

The implementation of `ArrayList#remove(E)` is as follows

```
public E remove(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    modCount++;
    E oldValue = elementData(index);

    int numMoved = size - index - 1;
    if (numMoved > 0)
        System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
                         numMoved);
    elementData[--size] = null; // Let gc do its work

    return oldValue;
}
```

Where `elementData` is the backing element array.

In words, it's not so much a shift, as it is a copy of elements, minus the element missing.

Given `elementData` with 10 elemetns

```
[ 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10]
                  ^ index 4
```

removing elements at index 4 would do

```
// copy elements starting from index+1
[ 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10]
                      ^ index+1

// to the same array starting at index
[ 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10]
                  ^ index     

// resulting in
[ 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | null ]
```

`get(4)` would then return value (6)`.

The [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29) api states

> Removes the element at the specified position in this list (optional
>   operation). Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one
>   from their indices). Returns the element that was removed from the
>   list.

How that is implemented is up to the implementor. The above is just `ArrayList`'s implementation.

Comment: @ppeterka66 I'll add that in too. OP asked about `ArrayList`, so I'll keep what I have.

Comment: I think it is good not only to provide a good answer for the question immediately at hand, but to give a generalized answer giving the asker opportunity to think in the right direction. Give a man a fish, and he'll ask for more. Teach him fishing, and he'll be all right.

Answer (score 2):

As specified in [List interface documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29), it will be shifted to the left.

Comment: This should be a comment if anything... But really this question should be closed.